# How to create circle progressBar on Android Wear

Tags: android, wear-os

How can i create circle progress bar on wear border like on [video](https://youtu.be/0xQ3y902DEQ?t=90)(1:30)? This is built-in widget or custom? I didn't find any information about this.
[screen from video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8ikl.png)

Comment: It would be better if you could [edit] a screenshot into your question so later visitors can see what you're talking about. The video you link to may be deleted at some point and future visitors won't be able see what you mean.

Comment: Ok, I added screen from video, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the [DelayedConfirmationView](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/confirm.html) from wearable support library.

Comment: The link is dead for DelayedConfirmationView

Answer (score 0):

If you scroll down about half way through this page you'll see the XAML for the Circular Progress Bar:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

```
<ProgressBar
  android:id="@+id/indeterminateBar"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />
```

The IndeterminateBar is default to Circle as it's undefined the actual 'Progress'